# How to run GWT template "MySampleApplication" in Intelij Idea?

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

I'm sorry for the stupid question.

I have Intellij Idea 13 and I created GWT template "MySampleApplication". If I try to run it I get this link:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/MySampleApplication.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

I open it in browser and it offers me to install developer plugin. I know that this plugin is up to date and not working. So how can I run this application? Using Super Dev Mod? SDM opens just code server page http://localhost:9876/

P.S. "If you are a customer we will do everything for you. If you are a developer - shut up and do everything youself." Is it normal that there is no word about this in GWT tutorial? I'm angry.

Comment: The plugin might not be working with some particular browser. Try with some different browser.

Comment: IE supports the GWT plugin. But I would suggest to use SDM. The easiest way to get SDM in Intellij running is to update to version 14 (ultimate). In version 14 running SDM is quite easy and described here: https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.1/getting_started/sdm/SuperDevMode_IDEA.html. Also use GWT 2.7.0.